# How to make a list of partially applied functions using map?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to make a list of functions (for use with `zipwith` later on) so that I effectively have `[take 1,take 2,take 3]` so each element of the list should have type `[Int] -> [Int]`.

This is what I've tried, which feels like it ought to be right. I'm not sure why I'm getting the error message?

```
Prelude> map (\x -> take x) [1..5]

<interactive>:46:1:
    No instance for (Show ([a0] -> [a0]))
      (maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?)
      arising from a use of ‘print’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: The error message just says that GHCi does not know how to print back the resulting list of functions. There's nothing wrong with the expression itself. You can still ask for the type of it with `:t`. That should work just fine.

Comment: Also, you can eta reduce the lambda: `map take [1..5]` works equally well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your code works. But functions cannot get `show`n. Try `show id`, and you end up with a very similar error message.

But before we delve into the application of your list of functions let us have a look at the types, just to check whether your logic is sound. For the sake of simplicity, we say that `1 :: Int`. Also, `\x -> take x` is just `take`, so we can reproduce your behaviour with `map take [1..5]`. Now we have the following participants in our little type turmoil:

```
map    :: (a -> b           ) -> [a]    -> [b]
take   :: Int -> ([c] -> [c])                   -- explicit parentheses
```

Now we plug `take` into `map`. In our `map`, `a ~ Int` due to `take`'s first argument, and `b ~ [c] -> [c]`. Therefore, we have

```
map take :: [Int] -> [[c] -> [c]]
```

Now we use `map take [1..5]`, which simply removes the type in our line above:

```
map take        :: [Int] -> [[c] -> [c]]
[1..5]          :: [Int]
map take [1..5] ::          [[c] -> [c]]
```

And we're done. We end up at exact the same type as in your error message. Does everything end up right? ***Yes. There's nothing wrong with your code.***

However, as already said, `[[c] -> [c]]` cannot get shown. We have to apply those functions in your list:

```
Prelude> map (\f -> f [1..10]) (map take [1..5])
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

@kosmikus answered your question in a comment, but here in case anyone is interested is what `:t` does in the in console.

Here is the list of 5 functions that you wanted, typed directly:

```
Prelude> :t [(take 1), (take 2), (take 3), (take 4), (take 5)]
[(take 1), (take 2), (take 3), (take 4), (take 5)] :: [[a] -> [a]]
```

Using your expression with `map`:

```
Prelude> :t map (\x -> take x) [1..5]
map (\x -> take x) [1..5] :: [[a] -> [a]]
```

Incidentally you can also say:

```
Prelude> :t map take [1..5]
map take [1..5] :: [[a] -> [a]]
```

What you can’t do is render the value itself in the GHCI console, there’s no way to show functions from lists to lists. The `:t` trick by @kosmikus is nice. That said, you *can* use your list of functions and see them in action. For example:

```
Prelude> let takers = map take [1..5] in head(tail takers) [8,9,10,11]
[8,9]
```

which applies the function `take 2` to the list `[8 9 10 11]`.